Obtaining rendered data (mapnik)
I want to extract data (city, town and village names) that will be visible when viewing at zoom levels 1 to 10.

You can see that even at zoom level 8, only few city/town/village names are visible
I am using a database (postgres), the map is rendered using mapnik. Unfortunately, I cannot choose another way.
Basically, I want to get a list of only those items that will be displayed at the selected zoom levels. I know that the data in the database is not marked with a zoom level; and that mapnik, based on the mapnik style file (xml), determines what will be displayed/rendered at a selected level and what will not.
But I cannot find a way (algorithm) to do this - how to calculate (and log/save) the items that will be displayed/rendered.

"mapnik" is a bit of software that's used in lots of different ways.  Depending on how your project uses it, the answer may be different.  https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/ covers one use of Mapnik.

@SomeoneElse, that's what is meant. For this use case I am looking for a way to get only those objects that have been displayed on the map. I do not need objects that have been hidden according to rules in the xml-file. Is this possible? Is it possible to log it somehow?

If the .xml file that Mapnik is using was created using "carto" (like this one of mine here) then the easiest thing to do is to find the source style (perhaps .mml and .mss files) and edit those.
If not, it is technically possible to edit Mapnik .xml files manually (it's just an XML file; you can edit it with a text editor), but is actually very complicated.  For example, a CartoCSS .mss file might contain:
[tourism = 'viewpoint'][zoom >= 16]::tourism {
  point-file: url('symbols/view_point.p.16.png');
}

which gets turned into
<Rule>
  <MaxScaleDenominator>12500</MaxScaleDenominator>
  <Filter><![CDATA[([tourism] = 'viewpoint')]]></Filter>
  <PointSymbolizer file="symbols/view_point.p.16.png" />
</Rule>

I guess you could experiment with CartoCSS examples and compare the resulting .xml output until you know what to change, but before you start doing that I'd definitely investigate where the Mapnik .xml came from.

I generally understand the syntax and purpose of .xml files, but I can't figure out how to get rendered objects (log during the renderd utility's work or calculate after tiles are generated).
